# Elasticsearsch Java API has_child

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm looking for how to build a query to fetch/search by children of parent document and I see that in `QueryBuilders` class up to ver. 1.7 there was `hasChildQuery` method ([documentation link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/has-child-parent.html))

```
// Has Child
QueryBuilder qb = hasChildQuery("blog_tag", termQuery("tag","something"));
```

**but since 1.7 there is nothing like this**

How to query for children then in Elasticsearch Java client? Why it was removed?

I'm using Elasticsearch in version `5.5.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that there is `JoinQueryBuilders` class that contains methods

```
public static HasChildQueryBuilder hasChildQuery(String type, QueryBuilder query, ScoreMode scoreMode)
public static HasParentQueryBuilder hasParentQuery(String type, QueryBuilder query, boolean score)
```

that allow you to query for a child/parent